# Move the selected string to first in comma separated string c#

Tags: c#

Move the selected string to first in comma separated string c#

If my csvstring is : C1,C2,C3
if my selectedstring is : C2

I require an output of : C2,C1,C3

Comment: What if there is more than one C2?

Comment: Just `Split` the string into an array, then you can manipulate the array however you like.

Answer (score 2):

Using the expression power of LINQ:

```
string cvsstring = "C1,C2,C3";
string selected = "C2";

cvsstring = string.Join(
              ",",
              new[] { selected }.Concat(cvsstring.Split(',').Except(selected));
```

If there are more than one selected instances, the duplicated will be removed by this code. As the question is very unprecise about that I won't give a solution (using `OrderBy`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty easy. Try below given code:

```
string csvstring = "C1,C2,C3";

string seletedstring = "C2";

string outputstring = selectedstring + csvstring.Replace(seletedstring .ToString(),"");

outputstring = outputstring.Replace(",,","");
```

Comment: What if cvstring becomes `"C1,C2,C3,C2,C4"`

Comment: @user1618587: Will the same string repeat in this scenario?

Comment: It doesn't work for moving the last item. If the input is `C1,C3,C2`, the ouput is `C2,C1,C3,C2` rather than `C2,C1,C3`.

Comment: Oh yes. Forgot to test that scenario. Now updated the solution. Thanks @Guffa

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
var str= "C1,C2,C3";
var selected="C2";
var result= string.Join(",", str.Split(',').OrderBy (s =>s==selected?0:1));
```

Comment: That will also sort the other items, i.e. if the input is `C3,C2,C1` the ouput will be `C2,C1,C3` rather than `C2,C3,C1`.

Comment: Noted. Updated the answer. This will not change the original order

Comment: like this , just a quick note on comparing strings : use culture info.:

string.Equals(s,selected,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 1):

You can split, sort and join:

```
string csv = "C1,C2,C3";
string selected = "C2";

csv = String.Join(',', csv.Split(',').OrderBy(s => s == selected ? 0 : 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var text ="C1,C2,C3";

var splits = text.Split(',');

var results =
    String.Join(",",
        Enumerable.Concat(
            splits.Where(x => x == "C2"),
            splits.Where(x => x != "C2")));
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. It really saved my lot of time!